# What word and form is うってる？

Tags: grammar, contractions

I'm reading a children's book (no kanji) and the sentence is:

> いどうはんばいしゃは、　みんなが　だいすきな　たべものを　うってるよ。

From the context, I figure it means:

> The mobile catering guy everyones favourite food selling

(I'm not good at particles)
My question is:
What is the form うってる?

I assume that よ is the emphasis-particle and the word is 売る - "to sell", because context, but I do not get the conjugation.
I checked [here](http://japaneseverbconjugator.com/VerbDetails.asp?JapaneseVerb=uru&VerbClass=1&EnglishVerb=sell), but the closest form I could find is "utte iru".

Answer (score 8):

売{う}ってる is an informal contracted form of 売って**い**る.

In the 〜ている construction, いる is a special type of verb called a "subsidiary verb" (or 補助動詞 in Japanese), a verb which serves a grammatical purpose rather than having its literal meaning, and [this type of verb very often contracts with 〜て.](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/18157/%E3%81%A6%E3%81%8A%E3%81%8F-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%8F-for-preparation-conjugation-and-nuance/18159#18159)

Answer (score 6):

売ってる is a contraction of 売っている. The い in ~ている verb endings is often dropped in casual speech.