# もらわれていくの grammar

Tags: grammar, て-form, passive-voice, subsidiary-verbs, nominalization

I have problem understanding grammar in this sentence:

> アニー、もらわれていくのがいやになったの。。。

Could you help to translate it and give links to grammar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's possible to explain the grammar (and that's what OP asked for)

- もらわ: The nai-form of the verb もらう ("to receive/get/take").
- れ: The te-form of the auxiliary verb れる, which forms the [passive voice](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/causepass).
- て: A conjunctive particle [that connects two verbs](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/compound).
- いく: A [subsidiary verb](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/18952/5010) which [describes the subject is (physically or emotionally) moving away from the speaker](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/teform).
- の: A [nominalizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominalization), which [turns verbs into nouns](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/nounparticles).

Thus, もらわれていくの literally means "(something or someone) being taken (by someone) (and going away)".

I think it's impossible to explain the actual meaning of this phrase, since you provided *no* context.