# what is "progressive form" in japanese?

Tags: words, meaning, verbs

I am making a Japanese verb conjugation app and can not seem to find the Japanese equivalent of "Progressive Form"

For example

```
辞書形 = dictionary form
命令形 = imperative form
可能形 = potential form
```

etc.

what is "progressive form" in japanese?
What term is used by Japanese textbooks?

Comment: http://jisho.org/search/progressive%20form

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Japanese term to refer to *English* progressive form (eg "I am sailing") is **進行形**（しんこうけい）. Every middle school students knows this term (they learn it in *English* classes).

By the way, I doubt there is a special 進行形 conjugation in Japanese. This concept is expressed in Japanese by simply using a [subsidiary verb](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/18952/5010) いる, preceded by て or で, preceded by so-called "te-form" of a verb. The "te-form" is known as one of the 連用形 to Japanese students who learn Japanese grammar at middle school.

Comment: im familiar with how the progressive form is conjugated, I am still adding it for completeness

Comment: Fine, now I understand what you're trying to do, so it's a lot easier to help :-)