# Is there a rule to writing verbs in hiragana or kanji when used as a suffix?

Tags: kanji, verbs, て-form

A common pattern I've noticed is for verbs like 行く and 来る after the て form of another verb. I know this is grammatically simply verb listing, but in terms of meaning the verbs often times sort of merge.

For example:

> やってくる
> 入っていく
> 登っていく
> 出てくる

I find that in these cases the second verb (くる / いく) is often times written in hiragana instead of kanji. Is this a rule?

Comment: See https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/34111/1628 and https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/18952/1628

Comment: @Earthliŋ Thank you, the first question is more or less a duplicate of mine. No clue why I didn't find it when searching. Voted mine as duplicate.

Comment: OK, thanks for confirming that this answers your question.