# "見てみて" , why is the second 見て in hiragana?

Tags: usage

Apparently it's a common way to write this phrase, at least on the web.

> 見てみてください

What's up with that?

I first encountered it on weblio

https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%22%E8%A6%8B%E3%81%A6%E3%81%BF%E3%81%A6%E3%81%8F%E3%81%A0%E3%81%95%E3%81%84%22

Some examples, the first results from google

https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1443775544

https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q11197208331

https://hinative.com/ja/questions/13962808

https://hinative.com/ja/questions/3923425

Comment: Duplicate? [Should I use ～てきた or ～て来た?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/34111/should-i-use-%EF%BD%9E%E3%81%A6%E3%81%8D%E3%81%9F-or-%EF%BD%9E%E3%81%A6%E6%9D%A5%E3%81%9F/)

Comment: It's better to include the full context. See [this meta post](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2189/what-should-i-do-if-i-was-asked-for-the-context-why-is-it-important?cb=1) please.

Comment: @Eddie Kal There's really no context. I just encountered it once, then googled it, and apparently it's very common to write the phrase this way. I'm just curious as to why.

Comment: @LonelyDriver Can you tell us where you saw it? Is it possible to include a link to the page?

Comment: I am extracting more context from you because I have a straightforward answer to your question that usually appies, and as you say the phrasing is not uncommom to see. But there are other possibilities where it could be something different, edge cases that defy the common situation.

Comment: @Eddie Kal I edited the post with some examples

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those two「みる」have different meanings and functions here.「みる」corresponds to several different verbs with different meanings and functions. To list a few: 「みる」、「見る」、「診る」、「観る」、「視る」、「看る」. Using different kanji suggests different shades of meaning and emphasis. 「見る」is the most commonly used rendition simply meaning "to see/look" in a generic sense.

「てみる」means to give something a try, to try and do something and see how it goes. It is usually written in kana, pursuant to official guidelines. The orthography of kanji and kana use has been codified in a cabinet directive [公用文における漢字使用等について（昭和56年内閣閣第138号）](https://www.bunka.go.jp/kokugo_nihongo/sisaku/joho/joho/kijun/sanko/koyobun/pdf/kunrei.pdf)which specifies suggested usage and orthography.

> 次のような語句を，(　)の中に示した例のように用いるときは，**原則として，仮名で書く**。
> 例
> 略...
> ・・・てみる(見てみる。)

The boldface words read:

> ...(these phrases) should be written in kana, in principle

And the example I quote here is exactly what you are asking about.

Therefore,「見てみる」means "to try and take a look" and usually translates as "take a look" with the suggestive "try" part implied. So 「見てみてください」would be "Please take a look."