# How can verb て become an adverb?

Tags: grammar, adverbs

I found a sentence

> 医者が「大丈夫ですか」と重ねて尋ねた。

with translation

> The doctor repeatedly asked "Is it OK?".

As far as I know

- The concatenation of て verb represents several actions which are done one after another. For example, 持って行く means "bring" followed by "go".
- Changing the last い in い adjective　to く makes it an adverb. For example, 早く来てくださいね.
- Or adding に after な adjective to makes it as an adverb. For example, 簡単に説明してください.

## Questions

How can 重ねて (to repeat) followed by 尋ねた (asked) become "repeatedly asked" ? Is there any grammar I am missing here?

Comment: +1. This is something I have never actually thought about; it always seemed natural to me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> The concatenation of て verb represents several actions which are done one after another. For example, 持って行く means "bring" followed by "go".

No, this is not always true. Te-form can combine two verbs like the English conjunction "and", but it does not necessarily mean the two actions happen one after another. For example, te-form can denote a method. 歩いて学校に行く means "go to school on foot" rather than "walk, and then go to school". Te-form is also used to express two things happening simultaneously. 立って話をする usually means "talk while standing" rather than "stand up, and then talk".

持って行く means "to have/hold" and "to go" occurring at the same time, hence the combined meaning of "to bring". (To be clear, 持つ alone does not mean "bring"!) In general, [these subsidiary verbs](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/18952/5010) do not represent two actions happening one after the other.

Now, the primary meaning of 重ねる is *to pile something up*, but the verb itself can mean *to repeat*. Here's デジタル大辞泉's corresponding definition:

> ２ ある物事に、さらにそれと同類の物事を加える。また、同じことを何度も繰り返す。「悪事を―・ねる」「努力を―・ねる」「年月を―・ねる」

The meaning of 重ねて尋ねる can be understood along the lines of 歩いて学校に行く and 立って話をする above. Here, the first verb before て describes how the second verb is done, in which situation the second verb is done, etc. That's why 重ねて尋ねる means "ask in a repetitive manner" rather than "repeat, and then ask".