# Can 続けて be used intransitively?

Tags: transitivity

From a definition of 降り続く：

> 雨や雪などが、何日も続けて降る。「—・く長雨にうんざりする」

If you boil this down to 雨が続けて降る it appears to make no sense if you consider 続ける as a transitive verb. What's going on?

Comment: It looks like an adverb.

Answer (score 2):

This 続けて is "continuously" that modifies 降る.

This is a te-form used *like an adverb* to modify how the action described by the second verb is done. 続けて can be remembered almost as a distinct adverb, but you can read the following questions for grammatical explanations:

- [How can verb て become an adverb?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/34647/5010)
- [立ってそばを食べる vs 立ちながらそばを食べる](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/62592/5010)
- [て form and adverbial meaning](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/38769/5010)

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is related to the construction

Stem+続ける which can be attached even to intransitive verbs.

I guess maybe it's just an inverted version of 降り続ける.