# What is the difference between "verb-stem + verb" and "verb-て form + verb"?

Tags: compound-verbs

例: 吸い取る 対 吸って取る

例: 噛み殺す 対 噛んで殺す

たしかに、意味は同じではないけど似ています。区別は何でしょうか。

What is the difference in meaning between the above verb pairs, and which construction would be used when?

Answer (score 4):

Some verbs carry *special* meanings only when they are used in the form of `te-form + verb` (ie, as a [subsidiary verb](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/18952/5010)):

- 読んでみる ([*]読み見る means nothing)
- 言ってもらう ([*]言いもらう means nothing)

Regardless of this, you can use almost any (non-subsidiary) verb after the te-form, as you know, and it mainly means "V<sub>2</sub> by V<sub>1</sub>" or "V<sub>1</sub> and V<sub>2</sub>":

- 走って逃げる
- 検討して回答する
- 食べて飲んで寝る

Some verbs carry *special* meanings only when they follow the stem of another verb. These are partly analogous to simple adverbs such as *out* as in *sell out*, *around* as in *go around* and *on* as in *live on*:

- 言い切る ([*] 言って切る usually means nothing)
- 呼び込む ([*] 呼んで込む usually means nothing)
- 動き出す ([*] 動いて出す usually means nothing)

Some verbs after the te-form have the meanings which are not really special, but tends to follow the verb-stem anyway:

- 噛み殺す (roughly the same as 噛んで殺す)
- 吸い取る (roughly the same as 吸って取る)
- 取り出す (roughly the same as 取って出す)
- 溺れ死ぬ (roughly the same as 溺れて死ぬ)

So... it depends. In your examples, 噛み殺す and 吸い取る are more common than 嚙んで殺す and 吸って取る. You will need the longer (te-form) version only when you want to explicitly say "V<sub>1</sub> **and then** V<sub>2</sub>", "V<sub>2</sub> **by means of** V<sub>1</sub>", etc.

Comment: 説明してくれてありがとう。お世話になったんだよ。とにかく、帆影五代目になったから楽しみに成ったと希望してるんだぜ。