# What does 仕入れて来る mean here?

Tags: words, usage, subsidiary-verbs

> Person A: そのちょっと変な写真だったって、えっと心霊写真みたいな
>   Person B: どこで**仕入れて来た**んだそんなような話

What does 仕入れて来た mean here? I know the dictionary definition of 仕入れる which is to stock up but I don't know its meaning here and can't understand its connection with 来る.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

仕入れる also means 'to gain new information that may be useful' and て来る(てくる) is called a kind of subsidiary verb - in this context, it means 'to get back after doing something'.

Actually in this situation, this て来る doesn't have much meaning because B just wanted to emphasize WHERE A heard that story.
So 'どこで仕入れたんだそんなような話' is almost the same as the original sentence.

For subsidiary verb, please refer below:

[What is a subsidiary verb?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/18952/what-is-a-subsidiary-verb)