# The meaning of 示してみせろ

Tags: meaning, subsidiary-verbs

> **その点に不服があるのなら、学校側が納得するようにこの1年間で示してみせろ。**

**示す**: 1. to (take out and) show; to demonstrate; to tell; to exemplify; to make apparent​, 2. to point out (finger, clock hand, needle, etc.)​, 3. to indicate; to show; to represent; to signify; to display.

**見せる**/**みせろ**: 1. show, 2. display.

I can't find any references related to **示してみせろ**, except in a song by a Japanese band **Lustknot.** "**Decayed My Skin**". One of the fans translate **示してみせろ** as "show a sign", but it's not quite fit the sentence I found in light novel.

I'm confused with the 2 words with an almost similar meaning put together into a word. I have a feeling that it simply means "to show", but it's like an emphasize, and perhaps "to show (with enthusiasm feeling)".

Thank you for your kind guidance.

Comment: This type of みせる is [a subsidiary verb](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/18965/5010) that means "to show someone doing ～" or "to surely do ～".

Comment: `I can't find any references related to 示してみせろ` <-- See: #10 in [this dictionary](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E8%A6%8B%E3%81%9B%E3%82%8B/#jn-211967) for the usage of the subsidiary verb (補助動詞) 「(～て)みせる」.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **示す**
>
> 1. to (take out and) show; to demonstrate; to tell; to exemplify; to make apparent​
> 2. to point out (finger, clock hand, needle, etc.)​
> 3. to indicate; to show; to represent; to signify; to display.

This is meaning 1 of course.

> **見せる/みせろ**
>
> 1. show
> 2. display.

It means to "make (something) clear" to the school, like "show them what's wrong". You could have for example がんばってみせろ = show them (みせろ) that you're capable of trying hard (がんばって), etc.

> I can't find any references related to 示してみせろ,

It's just the combination of two words, 示して and みせろ so I don't know why there would be references for that in particular.