# Saying "I'm going to sleep"

Tags: translation

Is 眠って行きます correct?
Is it Nemutte ikimasu or nemuttekimasu?
Informally.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to say "I will sleep", the Japanese equivalent is simply 寝ます or 眠ります.

眠って行きます is a grammatically correct sentence, but it means "I'll sleep here before leaving here".

Note that [the going-to future](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Going-to_future) is a grammatical construction of English, and it cannot be directly translated to other languages. (Likewise, you cannot translate "have to" as in "You have to sleep" using 持つ, because this "have" is special.)

(て)行く is one of the Japanese [subsidiary verbs](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/18965/5010). You can read about its usages [here](https://www.wasabi-jpn.com/japanese-grammar/helping-verbs/).

Comment: What about 眠って行く?
Because I want to say "I'll go to sleep (in my room)". Since I'm moving from a place to my room, using 行く is fine, right? Or am I totally wrong?

Comment: I believe that would be 眠りに行く or 寝に行く.

Comment: Please remember the most basic role of the te-form. 眠って行く is "sleep and then go/leave", not "go and then sleep". What you want to say is 部屋に行って寝ます, for example.

Comment: Oh.. Of course. I completely forgot that the て form is literally saying "and" or "then".