# What does 焦らしておいて mean? (NSFW warning)

Tags: て-form, sentence

やっぱりエッチなんですね

"As I thought we are going to have sex?" To which the other character replies

昨日散々焦らしておいてできなかったんだから

My reading is akin "yesterday I was left in suspense, because we didn't"

Comment: Please check if you copied them correctly, especially んですね and たんじゃだから.

Comment: You are right I correct

Answer (score 1):

The tricky part of this sentence is that the subject of 焦らしておく and the subject of できなかった are different. For the meaning of this -ておいて, see [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/88798/5010). んだから ("it's because") refers to everything before it.

> 昨日散々焦らしておいて、できなかったんだから。
>
> It's because **you** kept me in suspense but **I** couldn't do it yesterday.
> After all your teasing yesterday, I ended up not being able to do it, so...