# Usage of っ inbetween て and た forms?

Tags: verbs, conjugations

I have seen quotes in manga and games in which a verb will be presented as (If I remember correctly) "しまっていった" as opposed to "しまっていた".

Why is this? Is this an anomaly? Is one form intentionally used to convey a different meaning? If the latter is the case, what are the differences in meaning?

Comment: One is a form of ～ている and the other is a form ～ていく

Comment: I wonder if this っ is the same one in phrases like「しなくって...」.

Comment: This might be a little unrelated, but I have also seen a sentence like this “身元が今あらわしったので…” and wasn’t sure why instead of 現された they wrote しった.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

いた is the past form of いる, and いった is the past form of 行く. They are Japanese [subsidiary verbs](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/18952/5010) with completely different functions.

- **(-て)いる**: progressive form ("is V-ing") or continuation of a resultant state ("has V-ed")
- **(-て)いく**: physically or psychologically going away from the speaker; gradually over time toward the future; do something and leave

When used as a subsidiary verb, (-て)いく and (-て)いった are usually written in hiragana. See: [Difference between -ていく and -てくる](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/676/5010)

For example:

- 雪は溶けていた。
  The snow has (already) melted.
  <sub>(Someone only found a wet road and puddles.)</sub>
- 雪は溶けていった。
  The snow (gradually) melted away.
  <sub>(Someone was observing the melting process.)</sub>