# て-form for a cause/reason

Tags: conjugations, て-form

I just learned about this construction as detailed [here](http://www.learn-japanese-adventure.com/te-form-cause-reason.html). Wondering if I have it right. I understand that one use case is when what comes after the て-form verb describes a feeling, so I assume 欲しい counts?

「これはいいとよく言われて、野村さんが使って欲しいです。」

"It's often said that this is good, so I want Nomura-san to use it."

Or would 「これはいいとよく言われるから、野村さんが使って欲しいです。」 be more natural?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

「これはいいとよく言われて、野村さんが使って欲しいです」 doesn't sound natural to me, probably because the last part of this sentence is a kind of invitation. The linked page says:

> 2. Expressions containing volition/intention (will, order, invitation, request, permission, prohibition, etc) are not used in Sentence 2 *(=result part)*. When it contains volition/intention, the phrase with te-form (て-form) cannot be used and instead the phrase with から (kara) is used.
>
>    > 危なくて、機械に触らないでください。 X
>    >     abunakute, kikai ni sawaranaide kudasai X

And it's better to use the progressive form (te-form + いる) in the first part. Plus, when you say "I want *someone* to do something", the person has to be marked with に (see [this page](http://japanese.about.com/od/Grammar/a/Expressions-Of-Desire.htm) for examples). So some possible expressions are:

> first part
>
> - これはいいとよく言われていますから、……  (polite)
> - これはいいとよく言われているので、……
> - これはいいとよく言われてるんで、…… (casual; いる is [contracted to る](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/18159/5010) and ので is changed to んで)
>
> last part
>
> - ……野村さん**に**使って欲しいです。
> - ……野村さん**も**使って欲しいです。 (if you are also using it)
> - ……野村さん**にも**使って欲しいです。 (if you are also using it)

If there is no "intention" concerned, saying 「これはいいとよく言われていて (or 言われてて)、私も毎日使っています」, for example, is natural.