# using "natte'ta" in a sentence

Tags: word-choice, tense, sentence

in this sentence "natte'ta" is used:

"tsumetai ame zubunure ni natte'ta watashi ni"

i don't understand how the word "natte'ta" is used or its meaning. How would the word be translated to english and what tense is it in?

i'm really confused about the word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

なってた is the casual abbreviated form of なっていた ([see this chart](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/18159/5010)). なっていた is the te-form of なる followed by the past form of the subsidiary verb いる for denoting progressive/continuous aspect. なる is [this なる](http://jisho.org/word/%E6%88%90%E3%82%8B), and here it just means "to be". So 私はずぶ濡れになってた literally means "I was being soaked with rain."