# Question about verb 「ひっこんでろい」

Tags: verbs, て-form, manga

Here is the full sentence said by a young boxer to draw his coach out of the boxing ring.

> へっぽこセコンドは**ひっこんでろいっ**

If it is imperative form, I would like to know the grammatical difference between this form and 「ひっこめ」

Comment: Are you sure せこんど is not written in katakana?

Comment: Pray tell, do you have a source?

Comment: @Marco I'm sorry for my mistake. It is actually written in Katakana.

Comment: @user27280 If you mean the manga title regarding to this question, it is あしたのジョー

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- [ひっこむ](http://jisho.org/word/%E5%BC%95%E3%81%A3%E8%BE%BC%E3%82%80): "to butt out"
- (ひっこんで: te-form of above)
- ひっこんでいる: progressive form of ひっこむ
- ひっこんでる: [casual contraction of above](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/18159/5010)
- ひっこんでろ: imperative form of above
- ひっこんでろ**いっ**: This is an uncommon sentence-end particle used to emphasize the sentence. I think this ～ろい(っ) is seen almost exclusively in fiction, and it sounds masculine but a little childish. According to 明鏡国語辞典:

  > #### い
  >
  > 《肯定や命令の文の後に付いて》意味を強める。「早くしろい」「いやだい、ぼくがやるんだい」　【語法】助動詞「だ」「じゃ」などに付いた「だい」「じゃい」、終助詞「か」「わ」「な」に付いた「かい」「わい」「ない」、動詞の命令形に付いた「ろい」などの形で使う。

The difference from ひっこめ mainly comes from the "progressive" part. So it's more like "stay/keep away" rather than just "get away".