# Regarding chau and cha contractions, what happens in -って and -んで cases?

Tags: conjugations, contractions, subsidiary-verbs

When contracting -てしまう or -でしまう to -ちゃう or -ちゃ, what happens in the -って and -んで cases?

For example, does 洗ってしまう become あらちゃう or あらっちゃう?

Similarly, does 喚んでしまわない become 喚んじまわない or 喚じまわない?

I'm trying to write a conjugator, but my Japanese is limited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rule is fairly simple. Regardless of what comes before `て`/`で`:

- `てしまう` contracts to `ちゃう` or `ちまう`.
- `でしまう` contracts to `じゃう` or `じまう`.

The character before `て`/`で`, which is often `っ` or `ん` in godan verbs, must not be removed nor changed.

All of these conjugate like an ordinary godan verb such as 使う and 合う. Note that ちまう/じまう sounds fairly rough (it almost sounds like delinquent/gang speech in fiction).

Therefore:

- 洗ってしまう → 洗っちゃう (or 洗っちまう)
- 洗ってしまわない → 洗っちゃわない (or 洗っちまわない)
- 洗ってしまった → 洗っちゃった (or 洗っちまった)
- 呼んでしまう → 呼んじゃう (or 呼んじまう)
- 呼んでしまわない → 呼んじゃわない (or 呼んじまわない)

For other godan verbs:

- 泣いてしまう → 泣いちゃう (or 泣いちまう)
- 行ってしまう → 行っちゃう (or 行っちまう)

For ichidan verbs:

- 見てしまう → 見ちゃう (or 見ちまう)
- 食べてしまう → 食べちゃう (or 食べちまう)

---

[This chart](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/18159/5010) is helpful, too.