# Full っている vs shorter ってる: slang or official tool

Tags: verbs, slang

I know, that I can skip い in building continuous form of a verb.

> For example:
>   雪が降っている。
>   雪が降ってる。
>
> are equal and mean: [It's snowing.]

Question:
how legal is it to skip い in case like this?
Is it slang?
Is it error?
Or maybe it is a part of official Japanese language already?

Comment: You can expect a fine upwards of 1 000 000 ¥ and two weeks of jail time. So be very of careful dropping い if you ever were to visit Japan!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dropping of い is a very common *colloquialism*. It is heard in all sorts of informal situations, and kids probably learn how to say 降ってる before 降っている. You should use the long version in formal settings. There are [similar contraction patterns](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/18159/5010), and てる and ちゃう are especially common among them.