# What does 決まってんだろう imply?

Tags: phrases

Perhaps specific context is required but what is the real meaning behind this phrase?

Comment: @user3856370 Strictly speaking, no. There is no "explanatory-の" in this sentence.

Answer (score 4):

決まる means "to be settled" or "to be decided", and 決まっている means "has been (already) settled". But as a set phrase, (～に)決まっている also means "it goes without saying ～", "needless to say" or "certainly (although there is no direct evidence/guarantee)". See [JLPT N2 Grammar: に決まっている](https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%E3%81%AB%E6%B1%BA%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B-ni-kimatte-iru-meaning/)

By extension, when used as the reply to a question, 決まっているだろう/決まっているでしょう effectively sounds like "Why ask?" or "Of course, ～" or sometimes even "That's a stupid question". You can think of this as a set phrase to memorize.

決まってんだろう is a contraction of 決まっているだろう:

- 決まっ**ている**だろう: (literally) "It has been settled, hasn't it?"
- 決まっ**てる**だろう: ("teiru → teru" contraction described [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/18159/5010))
- 決まっ**てん**だろう: ("ru → n" contraction)