# 「辞めてった」 in お前のこと好きになって辞めてった女子も

Tags: grammar, て-form

I'm going through a dialog in a game and I came across some grammar I don't think I understand in the following sentence:

> お前のこと好きになって辞めてった女子も
> けっこう　いるって話じゃねーか！

What is the grammar behind `辞めてった`? I know this means something about quitting/leaving, but I have no idea how this was formed or what it actually implies.

My best guess translation, which I'm pretty sure is wrong, is something like

> he girls that like you, who something about having quit/left
> You could say that was great, couldn't you?

More context:

This sentence is said by `Male A` directed at `Male B`. Before speaking with `Male B` he was surrounded by a group of girls, who are totally falling head over heals for him. He tells the girls to go home and they immediately leave. `Male B` makes the comment that they like him instantly and that they are hard to get away from. `Male A`, just before saying the above, also implies that `Male B` more or less is cursing (呪い) the girls and that's why they act the way they do. This is all taking place in a university

Comment: I think what they quit has not been made clear in the context given. Is there anything said about any kind of activity prior to these lines? Jobs? Clubs? I know you've sketched out a plot context, but it is not quite clear what it is that they quit after falling for that person.

Comment: I honestly didn't even think about the overall setting. The overall setting takes place in a university. So its pretty safe to assume these girls are quitting/leaving university

Answer (score 3, accepted):

辞めてった is a contracted form of 辞めていった. See [this chart](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/18159/5010). Here ていく has the nuance of "gradually over time" plus "away from me/us/here/etc". See:  [Difference between -ていく and -てくる](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/676/5010)

Where did that "great" come from? The sentence means "I heard there are also quite a few girls who quit after falling love with you!" or "...girls who ended up quitting/leaving because they loved you". Does that make sense in the context?

Comment: That makes a lot more sense. I'm honestly more confused about the second part here now. I originally translated `けっこう` to `great` because that definition seemed to make the most sense at the time, since I saw it meant things like splendid, wonderful, and etc. But that seems to be a poor choice of wording. I'm still not sure what `けっこう` is supposed to mean though. Also, I'm not sure why いる is being used, but I am assuming the "I heard..." part is more in line with `いるって話じゃねーか` (Isn't that stories that are said?)

Comment: @Tylersansan Ah! I should have noticed けっこう could mean "great". Here けっこう is an adverb that means the same thing as かなり or たくさん. It corresponds to "quite a few" in my translation. いる is just "to exist". って話だ (=という話だ) is "I've heard ～", "They say ～", etc.

Comment: This is making a lot more sense now. Its clicking. Thanks for the explanation!