# 「していない」vs「してない」?

Tags: grammar, conjugations

From a search on here it looks like both are correct, but I couldn’t figure out the rules.

```
山下さんは結婚していないと言っていました。
```

Why is it 「していない」 and not 「してない」?

Comment: していない is formal.  してない is informal.

Comment: See [this chart](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/18159/5010) for similar examples of colloquial contraction.